# How to unit test task from private method

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I have a method (some code removed):

```
try
{
   var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(ValidateAccounts, _token);
}
catch (AggregateException)
{
   _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
   _token = _tokenSource.Token;
}
```

`ValidateAccounts` is a private method withing the same class. I would like to test that it was called and would like to be able to mock the task and try with the exception thrown and without it.

Comment: Unit tests are not meant to test internal behaviour of components but to guarantee output for a determined input. If there's something you can't test, you should probably reconsider your component architecture, access modifiers or just the way you test the behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you have to be careful when treading the fine line of what-to-test vs. what-**not**-to-test. It can lead to brittle tests that are too coupled with the implementation.

That being said, I absolutely see the utility in doing what you're trying to do. Testing the exception handling alone is worth asking this question.

The problem is rooted in your use of a static object (`Task.Factory`). Static objects/methods are notorious for impeding testability. The solution to this problem is the same used for decoupling *any* type of static object - introducing a [seam](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=359417&seqNum=2).

You are using the static object to kick off, and return a reference to, a `Task`. This is something that you can define a [role interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/RoleInterface.html) for. It might look something like:

```
public interface ITaskFactory
{
    Task StartNew(Action action);
}
```

With a production implementation that looks like:

```
public class TplTaskFactory : ITaskFactory
{
    public Task StartNew(Action action)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(action);
    }
}
```

You could then use dependency injection to supply your SUT with a mock implementation of this interface, which gives you the capability you're looking for.